# How to count all users where group id

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Can I use this `$this->db->where()` with codeigniter `count_all()`

Have i got the code correct below?

```
public function getTotalUsersByGroupId( $user_group_id ) 
{
    $this->db->where('user_group_id', (int) $user_group_id);
    return $this->db->count_all($this->db->dbprefix . 'user');
}
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Counts all users by there group id that's what I am trying to do

Comment: Have you tried running it to see what it does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`count_all()` is used to determine the number of rows in a particular **table**.
So instead you should use `count_all_results()` which is used to determine the number of rows in a particular **query**.

You can try this:

```
public function getTotalUsersByGroupId( $user_group_id ) 
{
    $this->db->where('user_group_id', (int) $user_group_id);
    return $this->db->count_all_results('your_table');
}
```

Comment: Still need to put the table name though

Comment: Getting there just found some bugs on my form fixing first let you know later